# meteor - _id of collection items returning with trailing garbage

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm returning collection results via a basic find() query and something odd is happening to the {{_id}} I'm receiving. Instead of just the unique id, I'm getting a bunch of trailing garbage that looks like other parts of the document. This is only happening for one collection - the exact same query works perfectly with all my other collections. I'm thinking it may have something to do with how I'm adding collection items, but I'm pretty lost. I can provide more info if needed, but I thought perhaps someone had encountered this before and could advise based on what I've described.

Here's what {{_id}} looks like for documents in the problematic collection:

```
3D5DWGh9n96BuiC4P""%7B"userId":"hJhLm8iBL9cQDEhzf","limit":10,"skip":0,"props":%7B%7D%7D
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

**NB:** Here's extra information I stupidly omitted the first time:

The trailing stuff is *not* returned when I do I find().fetch(). It's only when I use the easy-search package ( [link](https://atmospherejs.com/matteodem/easy-search) ) that this happens. Sorry for the lack of clarity earlier.

The helper:

```
Template.search.helpers({
    articlesIndex: () => ArticlesIndex
});
```

...relevant parts of the template:

```
{{> EasySearch.Input index=articlesIndex}}
<ul>
    {{#EasySearch.Each index=articlesIndex}}
        <li><a href="/article/{{_id}}">{{title}}</a></li>
    {{/EasySearch.Each}}
</ul>
```

The hrefs in the search results are where the problematic _ids are.

Comment: can you show the `template` and the `helper` code? how did you query and display the data ?

Comment: Could you use `DB.find().fetch()` in your browser console and see what it output... Is that still has this _id?

Comment: provide also template + helpers that you're using

Comment: Thanks all - I'll share code and fetch() results as soon as I'm back at my computer :-)

Comment: So, trailing stuff is not returned when I do I find().fetch(). It's only when I use the easy-search package ( [link](https://atmospherejs.com/matteodem/easy-search) ) that this happens. Sorry for lack of clarity earlier.

The helper:

 `Template.search.helpers({
  articlesIndex: () => ArticlesIndex
        });`

...relevant parts of the template:

`{{> EasySearch.Input index=articlesIndex}}
<ul>
 {{#EasySearch.Each index=articlesIndex}}
  <li><a href="/article/{{_id}}">{{title}}</a></li>
 {{/EasySearch.Each}}
</ul>`

The hrefs in the search results are where the problematic _ids are.

Comment: Okay, that's a mess! Let me update the original post with this information instead!

Comment: Actually, it looks like I've figured it out. According to the issues on github, _id is used by the package so I have to refer to __originalId instead. Here's a link in case it helps anyone else: [link](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/issues/347)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it looks like I've figured it out. According to the issues on github, _id is used by the package so I have to refer to __originalId instead. Here's a link in case it helps anyone else: [link](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/issues/347)